# Is it possible to make an environment or a command such that every word inside it is transformed into a TeX command?

Tags: macros

My purpose is to eliminate the use of backslash  in a long text where each word is supposed to be a command. For example, instead of `\def\new{this is a new command!}` `\def\another{Another one…}`  etc. and some  sequence of commands like `\new \another \c{c}` etc. I could  just type `\begin{myspecialENV} new another c{c}  \end{myspecialEnv}` or better  `\myspecialCom{ new another c{c} }` Is it possible? I have this problem because I am tring to make a package that uses a couple of  special commands to insert a series of musical symbols.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. What about cases like `\begin{myspecialenv} new another c{c{c}} \end{myspecialenv}`? (Note the `\myspecialCom` version would be easier.) It would be far more effective to configure your editor with the necessary shortcuts.

Comment: @Sean Allred I think that the user will never try c{c{c}} !  As I told before there exists many cases that everything inserted in is actuallly a command so it would be more faster and maybe more readable if the use of \ is hiden or eliminated inside this command..Also many users have not special editors for multiple replacements so I think is a good idea for such a special command

Comment: under `xelatex` you can use package [xesearch](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xesearch)

Answer (score 6):

I can't see any improvement in the input; however, if you love living dangerously, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myspecialcommand}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \tl_rescan:no { } { \c_backslash_str##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_rescan:nn { no }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\new{This is a new command}
\newcommand\another{Another one}

\begin{document}

\myspecialcommand{new another c{c}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/g49eY.jpg

Comment: @egreg I couldn't take an output!   The error is: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_backslash_str 
                            new
l.21 \myspecialcommand{new another c{c}}

Comment: @kornaros Please, update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do this but if I was going to do it, then:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand\new{This is a new command}
\newcommand\another{Another one}

\def\myspecialcommand#1{%
{\catcode`\ 0
\scantokens{ #1}}}

\begin{document}

\myspecialcommand{new another c{c}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder if one could make a list of commmands  like mycommands={ TeX, c, new, another, Do, Re, Mi} etc. so that one could have a better control of  what word  should be consider  as a command inside myspecialcommand!

Comment: @kornaros you could but seriously I wouldn't do this at all, if you want anything more complicated just pre-process the file with perl or python or any such similar system and make whatever substitutions are needed. But complicated input rules just makes it harder to input the document correctly compared to just requiring `\ `