# Is it possible to automatically replace commands shortcuts with the corresponding TeX commands?

Tags: macros

I would like to make a list of shortcuts like `myshortcuts={TeX, LaTeX, copyright, mycoommand }` etc. (`mycommand` is a  user-defined shortcut of a user-defined command) and a special command or enviroment so that each of the above words should be autommatically replaced by its coresponding command inside this special enviroment or command  ( like `\TeX`, `\LaTeX`, `\copyright` , `\mycommand` etc.) This question is a "revised" version of [Is it possible to make an environment or a command such that every word inside it is transformed into a TeX command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283627/is-it-possible-to-make-an-environment-or-a-command-such-that-every-word-inside-i)

Comment: Why can't you use the methods there?

Comment: It depends on your environment editor. Which text editor do you use ?

Or, If you use linux, you are able to modify your tex file with commands such as `sed`.

Comment: With any sensible text editor this is not a problem at all. Vim's LaTeX-suite does exactly that for a basic set of commands.

Comment: under xelatex you can use package xesearch

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for the package. It looks interesting. I have not linux, Vim only windows without power editors, In any case, thank you all for your interesting!

Answer (score 6):

The following solution is based simply on TeX macros.

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\bgroup \catcode`!=3 \catcode`?=3  % replacestrings from opmac.tex
\gdef\replacestrings#1#2{\long\def\replacestringsA##1#1##2!{%
   \ifx!##2!\addto\tmpb{##1}\else\addto\tmpb{##1#2}\replacestringsA##2!\fi}%
   \edef\tmpb{\expandafter}\expandafter\replacestringsA\tmpb?#1!%
   \long\def\replacestringsA##1?{\def\tmpb{##1}}\expandafter\replacestringsA\tmpb
}
\egroup

\def\setmacros#1{\def\setmacrosL{}\setmacrosA#1 {} }
\def\setmacrosA#1 {\ifx^#1^\else
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\setmacrosL\expandafter
      {\expandafter\replacestringsX\csname#1\endcsname{#1}}%
   \expandafter\setmacrosA \fi
}
\def\replacestringsX#1#2{\replacestrings{#2}{#1}}
\def\replacemacros#1{\def\tmpb{#1}\setmacrosL\tmpb}

\def\mycommand{Nazdar}

% test:

\setmacros{TeX LaTeX copyright mycommand}
\replacemacros{This is TeX. I don't use LaTeX. Here is an example of mycommand.}
```

**Edit** If you need to put replaced words in braces like `{TeX}` then you must `\detokenize` the replaced text first, then do replacement and then "retokenize" the text again:

```
\def\setmacros#1{\def\setmacrosL{}\setmacrosA#1 {} }
\def\setmacrosA#1 {\ifx^#1^\else
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\setmacrosL\expandafter
      {\expandafter\replacestringsX\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}%
   \expandafter\setmacrosA \fi
}
\def\replacestringsX#1#2{\replacestrings{#2}{#1}}
\def\replacemacros#1{\edef\tmpb{\detokenize{#1}}\setmacrosL
   \scantokens\expandafter{\tmpb}}
```

The reason is that the `\replacestrings` is only macro and it reads separated parameters. TeX hides separators in braces when the parameter is read.

Comment: I have only one problem. I can not use { } like {TeX} In this way I can not use commands inside other commands  I dont understand the  reason!

Comment: @kornaros OK, see "edit" part of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although I think it is *completely* inadvisable, the following more or less works, but can no doubt be broken very easily. Also, it requires `lualatex`.

For `\replaceMacros` to be an environment, I think some extra work would have to be done with category codes (similar to the `Verbatim` environment).

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
replaceMacros = function (input, macros)
  local s, x, y
  local list = {}
  string.gsub(macros, '(%a+)', 
    function(x) table.insert(list, x) end)
  input = ' ' .. input .. ':'
  for _, s in ipairs(list) do
      input = string.gsub(input, '%s('.. s .. ')([^%a])', 
        function(x, y)  
          if x and y then 
            if y == ' ' then  y = '\\space ' end
            return ' \\' .. x  .. y
          end 
        end)
  end
  return input:sub(2, input:len()-1)
end

\end{luacode*}

\def\setMacros#1{\def\currentMacros{#1}}
\setMacros{}
\long\def\replaceMacros#1{%
  \directlua{tex.print(%
    replaceMacros('\luatexluaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}', 
    '\currentMacros'))}%
}

\def\mycommand#1{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\replaceMacros{This is LaTeX which is built on top of TeX.
  Here is an example of mycommand{typewriter text}.
  And \textbf{Look!} \emph{Other macros still work}.
  copyright Me (2015).
}
\\[1em]
\setMacros{LaTeX, TeX, copyright, mycommand}
\replaceMacros{This is LaTeX which is built on top of TeX.
  Here is an example of mycommand{typewriter text}.
  And \textbf{Look!} \emph{Other macros still work}.
  copyright Me (2015).
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're using the `luacode` package, you could use its `\luastring` macro and write `\luastring{\detokenize{#1}}` instead of `'\luatexluaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}'`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any real usefulness of such a way of writing documents. But, just for playing around…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\registermacros}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl
   {
    (\seq_use:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq { | })
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\replacemacros}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:VnN \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl { \c{\1} } \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq
\tl_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\registermacros{TeX,LaTeX,copyright,mycommand}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{`Hello'}

\begin{document}

\replacemacros{This is TeX, in the LaTeX variant,
 I can set copyright and say mycommand.}

\end{document}
```

With also an environment form, that can be given an optional argument for additional (local) commands to be replaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% User interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\registermacros}{m}
 {
  \kornaros_replace_register:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\replacemacros}{m}
 {
  \kornaros_replace_main:n { #1 }
 }

\NewEnviron{replace}[1][]
 {
  \kornaros_replace_register:n { #1 }
  \kornaros_replace_main:V \BODY
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn  \kornaros_replace_register:n
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl
   {
    (\seq_use:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq { | })
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kornaros_replace_main:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:VnN \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl { \c{\1} } \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kornaros_replace_main:n { V }

\seq_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_macros_seq
\tl_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_macros_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kornaros_replace_text_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\registermacros{TeX,LaTeX,copyright,mycommand}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{`Hello'}

\begin{document}

\replacemacros{This is TeX, in the LaTeX variant,
 I can set copyright and say mycommand.}

\begin{replace}[textbullet]
textbullet This is copyright
\end{replace}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: kornaros inside a command! I don't believe it!!!

Answer (score 2):

A solution with ConTeXt, I'm not sure if it's polished (apart from the fact that may be I'm not using it correctly)

```
\usemodule[translate]


\unexpanded\def\examplecommand#1{{\tt#1}}

\translateinput[ConTeXt][\CONTEXT{}]
\translateinput[TeX][\TeX{}]
\translateinput[copyright][©]
\translateinput[examplecommand][\examplecommand]


\starttext

This is ConTeXt which is built on top of TeX.
Here is an example of examplecommand{typewriter text}.
And \bold{Look!} \emph{Other macros still work}.
copyright Me (2015).

\enableinputtranslation

This is ConTeXt which is built on top of TeX.
Here is an example of examplecommand{typewriter text}.
And \bold{Look!} \emph{Other macros still work}.
copyright Me (2015).

\disableinputtranslation

This is ConTeXt which is built on top of TeX.
Here is an example of examplecommand{typewriter text}.
And \bold{Look!} \emph{Other macros still work}.
copyright Me (2015).

\stoptext
```

[image]